# Angular JS how to update scope variable inside another scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am bulding a list using ng-repeat from array of objects. One of the property in array is a boolean that will go in ng-show of each element I am building using this array. Array itself is a scope variable too.

Now I want to update display property only. Is it possible?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.displayThird = false;

  $scope.list = [
    {
      text: "One",
      display: true
    },
    {
      text: "Two",
      display: true
    },
    {
      text: "Three",
      display: $scope.displayThird
    },
    {
      text: "Four",
      display: true
    }
  ];

  /* I want this function to update my display property */
  $scope.display = function() {
    $scope.displayThird = true;
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kF1M1fWyeCcrfcUY3Aqu?p=preview

Comment: is this what you are trying to do?  http://plnkr.co/edit/1S4AWMQ1gLUr9li03Xje?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, ultimately this is what I wanted to achieve. But I wanted something where I don't need to specify array index, incase I don't know it. Nikos' answer helped me realise why I couldn't do it the way I wanted.

Comment: you can pass in the specific item also, then get it's index from within controller. `var idx= $scope.list.indexOf(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception: When you assign an expression to a variable *in Javascript*, only the *value* of the expression gets assigned. No *binding* gets created. On the contrary, expressions in Angular templates *do* create bindings.

Therefore in your case the `$scope.list[2].display` gets assigned the value `false` and knows nothing how this value was created.

The correct way to do this in Angular is with a watch:

```
$scope.$watch("displayThird", function(newval) {
    $scope.list[2].display = newval;
});
```

This is what Angular does under the hoods with its templates, only you have to do it manually in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was hoping there's some secret angular method to let it know that this is a scope variable to watch. Thanks for a quick response.